# Python - Indices of top n elements in each column of numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

What is the best way to select top n elements from each column of a numpy matrix of 2 dimension?(apart from using for loop)

Comment: Look at `argsort` or `argpartition`.

Comment: @Anooj-Gandham Do you mean how to get data from the first n rows?

Comment: I have to repeat argsort for each column right in a for loop? I dont want to use for loop if there is a numpy function available.

Comment: I have a dataset and I want the top n elements(in descending order) in each column for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe slicing?

if you have:

```
matr = np.random.randn(4, 5)
```

you can simply select for example first 2 elements of first 2 cols doing:

```
matr[:2,0:2]
```

Try those snippets of code and check if it's what you was looking for.